# Swapping a healthy and unallocated partition in Windows 10

Tags: operating-system, windows-10, partition

I was running a dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu on my machine and after several weeks, I decided to keep Linux on another machine as dual booting was a bit inconvenient for me. I've since deleted the Unix OS from my machine and have a 500GB partition that is unallocated and wasted memory. [Here's what my partitions look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g339D.png). If the image fails to load for you (not high enough rep to embed images), the important partitions are laid out like this:

[C: (514GB)] - [Healthy Partition (7.5GB)] - [Unallocated (412GB)]

Every solution so far says to move the unallocated partition next to C: and merge the two; however, Windows' disk management app refuses to give me this option, and I'm nervous about deleting the healthy partition since I don't know what it does. I've tried everything else except 3rd party software to move the unallocated partition over next to C: and merge them together, but I've been unsuccessful so far. Do any more Windows-savvy people have suggestions on how I can reclaim this half-terabyte space without a clean re-install?